# Babel const prevents mutation?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm writing tests in ES6 syntax powered by Babel, and I'm using Jest to run the tests. Here my test code:

```
test('case: response body contains a user, should update sessionData', () => {
  // current user info in the session
  const currentUserInfo = {
    firstName: 'User1',
    lastName: 'Old Info'
  }

  const mockSessionData = createSessionHelper(
    {
      data: {
        user: currentUserInfo
      }
    },
    mockLogger
  )

  // new user info in the body
  const newUserInfo = {
    firstName: 'User2',
    lastName: 'New Info'
  }

  const body = {
    user: newUserInfo
  }

  const result = handleSuccess({
    req: {
      sessionData: mockSessionData
    },
    body
  })

  expect(result.status).toBe(DEFAULT_SUCCESS_STATUS)
  expect(result.body).toEqual(body)
  expect(mockSessionData.get('user')).toEqual(newUserInfo)
})
```

As you can see, I'm using the same objects both to use as parameters to the functions I'm testing and, to match the result with my expectation.

I'm assuming here that these functions should not mutate those parameters. Is this assumption true, though?

By using Babel `const`, will my data remain the same, or should I still use `Object.freeze()`?

Comment: `const` doesn't do anything to the value you assign to it.It doesn't force immutability of the value. `const` just means you can't reassign it. `const a = []; a.push(1); console.log(a)` - works. But `const a = []; a = [];` - doesn't

Comment: Immutable **bindings** (`const`) and immutable **values** (`Object.freeze`) are two different things. An immutable binding may hold a mutable value and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) says,

> The value of a constant cannot change through re-assignment, and it can't be redeclared.

`mockSessionData` cannot be re-assigned. `const` can't and shouldn't prevent an object that `mockSessionData` holds a reference to from being modified.  `Object.freeze` may be used if the object shouldn't be changed.